# apache url rewrite not removing the IP address from the url

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I've got the following virtual host set up in my AWS EC2 apache.

```
<VirtualHost 99.999.999.999:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite
ServerName site.com

 # Other directives here ...

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

However it is still showing the url as 99.999.999.999/directory/index.php

I've followed the setup and I'm wondering if there's something I've missed here?

The result I'm expecting is that when I type www.site.com into my browser it goes to www.site.com/directory/index.php. Currently typing this will send me to 99.999.999.999/directory/index.php.

I was under the impression that setting the virtual host in the way I've defined would stop the ip address being shown and instead display the ServerName as site.com

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I assume you wanted your url to be site.com/directory/index.php.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: How are you arriving at showing "x.x.x.x/directory/index.php" ?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualHost won't **rewrite** the URL when you access it by IP address.

For example, you can access Google with `http://www.google.com` or `http://74.125.20.105/`

If you go to the IP address, it will show the IP, if you go to the named domain, it will go to the name. Try just using the name.